# How do you capture video of your PS3 gameplay?

Tags: ps3, recording

I'd like to be able to capture  video of me playing games on my PS3, especially when earning difficult trophies, or getting past tricky levels so I can share my techniques/tricks with others.

Obviously, I could just point a camera at the screen, but the quality of the capture is extremely poor and would take up physical space in the area where I normally sit to play.

What's the best way to capture that so I can post it to YouTube, Vimeo, etc?

Can I use Mac OS X? Windows? What hardware do I need? Software?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13705/how-do-you-capture-video-of-your-wii-gameplay - most (if not all) of the solutions for one console will work on the others.

Comment: I thought they would be different because they use different outputs, i.e. HDMI vs. component vs. composite.  Plus, I'm looking for specific, not generic, advice.

Comment: @ChrisF agreed, unless maybe there's some way to capture from HDMI output which would allow a better quality than the methods that apply for the Wii. (edit: sorry, wrote this before I saw the comment from splattered bits)

Comment: in that case ask a specific question about capturing from HDMI which would apply to both PS3 and Xbox 360

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not certain whether Sony activates HDCP on their HDMI during gameplay.  There are HDMI capture cards, but HDCP would throw a brick in your ability to capture HDMI.  A much more sure way to capture HD would be to use a [component cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000MIXFWA) and a [Hauppauge HDPVR](http://www.hauppauge.com/site/products/data_hdpvr.html) hooked to your PC.

Comment: And to think I received flack for choosing component over HDMI... lol

Comment: The HDCP is only activated when watching movies or using applications like Netflix. At least that's how it is on the Xbox 360.

Answer (score 1):

You know, the way I used to do it was to output the video through a DVD recorder with a HDD and then record the session, and then transfer the recording to my laptop to further edit or just upload.  If you already have a DVD recorder or similar device, this seems to be the simplest thing I can think of.