# How to record long fight in Super Smash Bros. Brawl?

Tags: super-smash-bros-brawl

So I'm really addicted now to Super Smash Bros. Brawl and I want to know how to record my long battles. Now, Super Smash Bros. Brawl gives you the option to record your fights if their under like one or two minutes, but is it possible to record my longer fights? I'm assuming that I'll probably have to put in a SD card but I don't know if it's possible at all. Could someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

SSBB only captures up to three (3) minutes of gameplay. If your fight takes more than 179 seconds it will stop to record the match and the game will not provide you an option to safe your fight.

However, according to [SmashWiki](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Replay), you can extend the recordings/replays up to 10 minutes if you're willing to modify your Wii's system software (not recommended). Fights longer than 10 minutes still won't work.

If you really want to record fights longer than that, [you will need additional hardware](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/13705/39762).

Comment: So without additional hardware or modification there is no way to record longer(aside from pointing a camera at the screen)?

Comment: @gamer103 Correct.