# How do you take screenshots in GTA V?

Tags: ps3, grand-theft-auto-v

I would like to take screenshots in GTA V on my PS3, but it's not possible from the XMB bar. I looked around on the Internet and I see a lot of people talking about a capture card, but these are for video recording right?

Is there any way that I can take screenshots (not videos) from GTA V?

Comment: If there is no in-game options for it, it is likely that the screenshots you are seeing are screenshots taken from the video produced by capture cards.

Comment: if that's the case, i'm gonna have to search the solution outside of the game. do you know any soft/hardware that allows me to take screenshots from this game?\

Comment: You may want to check these two questions: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13704/how-do-you-capture-video-of-your-ps3-gameplay and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13705/how-do-you-capture-video-of-your-wii-gameplay for the video capture side of things.

Comment: I thought it was possible by using your cellphone(smartphone actually) camera. To access it just press **UP** on the *D-pad* and then choose *Snapmatic*. I think it should then somehow be extractable via XMB

Comment: I tried that, it uploads the picture to social club but they give the photo this old-cellphone effect, like on instagram. those screenshots are useless

Comment: @Imaginedigital - Using a capture card is your alternative solution if the in-game screenshots are not good enough.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a PC video capture card, you could route the TV output to it.