# How do you take screenshots on Assassins Creed IV on the PS3?

Tags: ps3, assassins-creed-4-black-flag

Maybe there just isn't a way for some sort of copy write purpose. I tried to plug in a USB keyboard and hit printscreen, but when I went to look for it under photo, the only thing that was close to what I was looking for was a software called Photo Gallery that I could only use if you download the software which I can't do because I don't have internet. I scoured the entire system layout. Do I need internet to print screen? Is there a different keystroke? Is there a way to maybe do it with the controller? Where would I look for the photo after I do the keystroke? Is this even possible?

I have been trying to get the map the way Assassins Creed IV has it for a project I'm doing, and Google Maps and other places won't do. I want the Assassins Creed archipelago and can't bypass this hurtle. How can I get a screenshot?

Comment: My copy of AC3 is in a different time-zone from myself right now so I cannot test if this game supports it and therefore am not posting it as an answer, but as per [this](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-General/How-to-take-a-screenshot/td-p/37100876), the default PS3 shortcut for screenshots is (PS)+<Start>, but it has to be enabled per-game and few games have it. If nothing else, it's worth a shot...a screen shot.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a reasonable question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't take screenshots of PS3 games directly from the system, unless the game specifically has the option to do so in game. Apparently ACIV isn't such game.

Your best bet is to either capture screenshots "off-screen", i.e. Us a camera directed at your TV, or go the the more expensive route and output your PS3 through a video capture device, such as those detailed [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13704/how-do-you-capture-video-of-your-ps3-gameplay) or [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13705/how-do-you-capture-video-of-your-wii-gameplay).